# Load multiple SVGs into javascript array without DOM append

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'd like to do the following:

```
function loadSvg(path) {
  d3.xml(path, 'image/svg+xml', function(xml) {
    return xml.documentElement;
  });
}

d3.json(jsonOfSvgFileNames, function(paths) {
  // paths = ['pathName','pathName2',...]
  var svgList = [];

  for(var p in paths) {
    var path = paths[p],
        svg = loadSvg(path);
    svgList.push(svg);
  }
});
```

I'm running into the problem of the `xml.document` objects disappearing once `d3.xml` calls are finished. I know that this issue of permanency can be a problem for other types of server calls, but I'm not sure what keywords I need to use to find an answer.

While one answer is to issue a server request on demand and then append an SVG to the DOM in a `d3.xml` call, this is not an option for my application. Time is important in my application and even a 300ms wait is too much, which is why I'd prefer doing a batch load.

Ninja-edit: I found out that this is because of the async call, and the object getting pushed into the array before it is loaded. Would promises be an acceptable solution to this (e.g., `load().then(push)`)? I haven't worked with promises too much. Is there an accepted standard library for promises?

Comment: You could push the svg onto the array inside `d3.xml`.

Comment: I was thinking something similar to Lars.  Copy what you want to a different memory location before the function completes.

Comment: I've also tried doing that, but there's still the async issue to deal with. It does eventually push into the array, but there's no guarantee as to when it will get populated. The more I look at it the more promises seem like they're the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promises are indeed the way to go:

```
var svgs = [];

$.when( loadData('gridList.json') ).then(function(status){
  console.log( status )
  for (var i = 0; i < svgs.length; i ++){
    $("body").append(svgs[i]);
  }
})


function loadSVG(path){
  var dfd = new jQuery.Deferred();
  d3.xml(path, 'image/svg+xml', function(xml) {
    svgs.push( xml.documentElement );
    dfd.resolve("loaded " + path);
  });
  return dfd.promise();
}


function loadData(jsonFile){
  var dfd = new jQuery.Deferred();
  d3.json(jsonFile, function(paths) {
      for( var i = 0; i < paths.length; i++ )
      $.when( loadSVG(paths[i]) ).then( function(status){
        console.log( status );
        if (svgs.length == paths.length)
          dfd.resolve( "All SVGs loaded!" )
      });
  });
  return dfd.promise();
}
```